# How far can the plane be tiled by congruent regular pentagons?

Tags: geometry, optimization, packing-problem, tiling

What is the limit, as the radius of the disk increases, of the greatest area, in proportion to the area of the disk, of the region covered by regular pentagons of the same fixed size, all lying within a large disk and not overlapping (except perhaps at boundary points)?

Comment: Not an answer, but related to the reverse question of circles in a pentagon: http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/cirinpen/

Comment: Some info on tilings with pentagons: ["The trouble with five"](https://plus.maths.org/content/trouble-five)

Comment: Thanks, @Blue, for the interesting link. The left-hand diagram of Fig. 8 looks promising. If my calculation is correct, that configuration would tile $\frac3{11}(10-3\surd5)\approx0.897762563$ of the plane.

Answer (score 3):

You posted only two weeks too early!

This question is more concisely phrased as asking for the maximum packing density of the regular pentagon. This had long been conjectured to be $\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}3\approx0.92131\ldots$, but was only resolved in the affirmative by [Hales and Kusner](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07220) on Feb 23, 2016. The optimal packing looks like this:

[image: https://blogs.ams.org/visualinsight/2014/12/01/packing-regular-pentagons/]